# Two way data binding doesn't work for the first time. angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a text box to which I applied the daterange picker. Upon selecting the dates I am getting the data from backend and populating to a field in UI. Here 
Two way binding doesn't work for the first time. It works fine from second time onwards.

Here is my code :

js file :

```
  $('#txtDateRange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        $scope.isRefreshing = true;
        $scope.Model.DateTo = $filter('date')(new Date(picker.endDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
        $scope.Model.DateFrom = $filter('date')(new Date(picker.startDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
        $scope.Model.typeAvailability = picker.chosenLabel === "Custom Range" ? "Custom" : picker.chosenLabel;
        $scope.$apply();
        $scope.FilterByDate();
    });

 $scope.FilterByDate = function () {
        if ($scope.selectedItem == null || $scope.selectedItem == 'undefined') {
            $scope.BetweenDatesFilter = $filter('filter')($scope.Summary.CorpEmployees, function (o) {
                return (new Date(o.startDate) > new Date($scope.Model.DateFrom)) && (new Date(o.startDate) < new Date($scope.Model.DateTo));
            });

            $scope.NewEmps = $scope.BetweenDatesFilter.length;
            $scope.otcScred = $scope.BetweenDatesFilter.length;
      }
 };
```

HTML :

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="text" id="txtDateRange"
                               class="form-control input-md" name="txtDateRange"
                               placeholder="Select Range"
                               ng-model="Model.RageDates" />
     <span class="form-control-feedback"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
     <span style="color: #a94442">
     <label class="control-label" class="has-error" ng-show="txtDateRange.$invalid">Required.</label>
     </span>
 </div>


    <div id="divSmry" class="img-fluid">

       <img src="~/Content/Images/wotc/SummaryTop1x.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" style="position:absolute;left:75px;" />
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showOptionsMenu('E', 'Wotc', 'glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'); LoadViewSelected('/otc/otc/otcDashBoard', 'WotcDashBoardModule', 'CorporateComplianceEmployees');">
       <span style="position:absolute;left:125px;top:165px;font-size:40px">{{NewEmps}}</span>
       </a>
       <span style="position:absolute;left:245px;top:165px;font-size:40px">{{otcScred}}</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$('#txtDateRange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {` doesn't trigger a digest cycle, so your view never updates.

Comment: what am i missing there to trigger the digest cycle.

Comment: Few ways to force it... `$scope.$apply()` after your code or wrap it all in a `$timeout`

Comment: every time you write $('#... in angular one kitty dies. Never do this again.

Comment: @Petr  it was a jquery plugin I was implementing.  What would be the best approach in this case.

Comment: Wrap each plugin into angular directive ofc. (But best is stop using jquery at all, angular bootstrap has an ok datepicker)

Comment: Thank u @tymeHV that helped. Because you wrote it as a comment I am unable to accept it as answer. If you can put the same in answer I can accept.